# Расширенный поиск : Требует правки

Tags: предложение

В расширенном поиске не хватает поиска вопросов с меткой "требует правки".

Поиск закрытых вопросов есть `closed:yes`, а что выше - нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для поиска вопросов, требующих правки можно использовать следующий запрос:

> [closed:yes created:5d.. duplicate:no migrated:no](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3Ayes%20created%3A5d..%20duplicate%3Ano%20migrated%3Ano)

В некоторых пограничных случаях могут проскакивать действительно закрытые вопросы, но в основном работает.

5 дней — это срок, в течение которого вопрос висит как [требующий правки] до того как будет закрыт по-настоящему.

Comment: Выдала только закрытые вопросы. Сам задумался "А нужна вообще эта функция?" Всё равно вопросы потом закрываются, дело времени.

Comment: @stackflow см. не по заголовкам в результатах поиска, а после открытия страницы вопроса из этих результатов поиска.

Comment: @alexolut, а это не баг, что заголовок на странице поиска неверно отображается?))

Comment: @Qwertiy [баг](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302452/339911)

Comment: @Qwertiy уже исправлено.